# AngularJS: How to pass the id through a service method in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I am developping an AngularJS webapp.
I have following routeconfig:

```
  $routeProvider.
    when("/drivers", {templateUrl: "partials/drivers.html", controller: "driversController"}).
    when("/drivers/:id",{templateUrl: "partials/driver.html", controller: "driverController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/drivers'});
}]);
```

So to pass the ID of JSON, I use following method in my service.js file

```
F1API.getDriverDetails = function(id) {
        return  $http({
            method: 'JSONP', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/app/data/' + id + '/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    }

    F1API.getDriverRaces = function(id) {
        return  $http({
            method: 'JSONP', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/app/data/' + id + '/results.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
        });
    }

    return F1API;
  });
```

But now there is the part where I'm stuck. I need this method to assign a driver and his races in an object. But I need the id for this, so I tried in my **controller.js**

```
/* Driver controller */
controller('driverController', function($scope, $routeParams, F1APIservice) {


    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.races = [];
    $scope.driver = null;

    F1APIservice.getDriverDetails(id).success(function(response){
      $scope.driver = response.MRData.StandingsTable[0].DriverStandings[0];
    });

    F1APIservice.getDriverRaces(id).success(function(response){
      $scope.races = response.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
    });
});
```

Id is unknown while I build my webapp. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, you assign `$routeParams.id` to `$scope.id`, but then you call `getDriverDetails` and `getDriverRaces` with just `id`, which is undefined. You need to call them like this: `getDriverDetails( $scope.id )`.

Comment: Ok I see, I'm going to try it.

Comment: also can use `F1APIservice.getDriverDetails($routeParams.id)`

Comment: That's also an option. If you don't need the ID to exist on the `$scope`, there's no reason to reassign it from `$routeParams`.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to decouple your controller from `$routeParams`. To achieve that use `$routeProvider`'s `resolve` functionality:

```
$routeProvider.
    when("/drivers/:id", {
        templateUrl: "partials/driver.html",
        controller: "driverController",
        resolve: {
            'id': function($route) {
                return $route.current.params.id);
            }
        }
    })
```

Using the above, Angular will make `id` available to your controller:

```
controller('driverController', function($scope, id, F1APIservice)
```

Since `resolve` is promise aware, an alternative approach could even be to do your service call inside resolve:

```
$routeProvider.
    when("/drivers/:id", {
        templateUrl: "partials/driver.html",
        controller: "driverController",
        resolve: {
            'driver': function($route, F1APIservice) {
                return F1APIservice.getDriverDetails($route.current.params.id);
            }
            'races': function($route, F1APIservice) {
                return F1APIservice.getDriverRaces($route.current.params.id);
            }
        }
    })
```

The `driver` and `races` get injected into your controller:

```
controller('driverController', function($scope, driver, races, F1APIservice)
```